# Inherited value of variable is 0

Tags: java

I am a beginner and I am trying to inherit the value of a variable in another class.The Value I get is 0 which is should be 10.

First class:

```
public class assignment
{
    int var = 10;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        initialize pere = new initialize();
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println(" pere.invariable: "+pere.invariable);
   }
}
```

Second Class inherits var from class assignment:

```
public class initialize
{
    public static int  invariable;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
       assignment variable = new assignment();
       System.out.println(" variable.var : " + variable.var);
       invariable = variable.var;
       System.out.println(" invariable: " + invariable);
    }
}
```

Why is `pere.invariable = 0` and yet I have inherited invariable(in 2nd class) which is = 10?

Comment: Please consider utilizing a code-block to make your sample code more readable.

Comment: @Andreas I thought I spotted "extends" somewhere in that badly formatted code dump.

Comment: You have two `main` methods, but only one of them executes the code that sets the value of `invariable`, and it's not the one you're executing.

Comment: You asking about `pere.invariable`, which is only present in the `assignment` version of method `main`. Since the 2 `main` methods are entirely independent of each other, none of the code in the `initialize` version of method `main` is executed, so why would you expect the value to be anything other than the default of `0`?

Comment: And Andreas is fully correct: there is zero inheritance going on here. Assigning one int to another doesn't "connect" the two fields. You simply assign values,!?

Comment: Okay my apologies , I am trying to get the value of a variable in another class i.e the value of "invariable" whis 10 but pere.invariable gives me 0

Comment: @Andreas So how do I go about it?, i would like pere.invarible(in assignment class) to obtain the value of invariable(in initialize class)

Comment: @ROY You need to run the other `main` method.

Comment: They both run the way I want them to, the only problem is the value of pere.invariable != invariable

Comment: Just an FYI, class names should be capitalized by convention

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion here is stemming from a few places.

There is no inheritance happening here.  Inheritance is something that happens to a class.  For example,

```
public class A {}

// B extends A
public class B extends A {}
```

The "entry point" for a class is normally it's constructor.  `main` is not a constructor, it's the entry point for a Java application (it's main function).  A constructor is a function labeled with the classes name.  For example:

```
public class B {
    public B() {
        // I am inside a constructor
    }
}
```

The way your code is situated now, `initialize` main function is never called.  You either need to call it manually from your `assignment` main function, or you need to turn it into a constructor (changing the name of it and removing the static modifier, as in my example).

This looks like a school assignment. As far as I'm aware, StackOverflow has a policy against answering questions for school assignments directly, but I hope that this answer can at least help clear up some confusion and help point you in the right direction.

Comment: The help centre makes no references to such a policy, it might have been policy at some point in the past but it doesn't appear to be one now. Whether that's a good thing or a bad thing is a discussion for meta!

Comment: Got it. That said, from a personal standpoint, I flat out refuse to give people answers to assignment questions :)

Comment: As do I - personally I think just giving them the answer is a disservice to them as it robs them of the opportunity to learn

Comment: Kindly note this is not an assignment, I am just trying to teach myself how to code